# How to block URL's on textarea in a contact form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I'm receiving some unwanted links though the contact form, how to restrict the user or bot to enter URL link on the textarea?

I have done so many google searches but none of them worked for me, tried some libraries too like jquery validation but I couldn't find the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply have a list of "banned" URLs and check if any are included in the value of the textarea.

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
const errorP = document.getElementById('error');

const bannedUrls = [
  'google.com',
  'reddit.com',
  'stackoverflow.com',
];

textarea.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const bannedUrlsInInput = bannedUrls.filter(url => textarea.value.includes(url));
  if (bannedUrlsInInput.length > 0) {
    errorP.textContent = `${bannedUrlsInInput.join(', ')} not allowed`;
  } else {
    errorP.textContent = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
<p id="error"></p>
```

Note that this is not the most performant way. If you have thousands of banned domains, you should consider using the exotic Bloom filter data structure.

And last but not least -- if this validation is truly critical, it is not enough to just do client side validation, you need some server validation too.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question, kindly please read it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match

```
if($_POST){
 !preg_match(^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.[a-z]{2,6}(\/)?$, $_POST);
 $error = 'links are not allowed';
return $error;
}
```